# PHP 5.3, Suhosin and UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, suhosin

I'm struggling to find a solution to keep using the Suhosin patch and make it work with UTF-8 form submissions. This is the very simple test I made:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
<form method="post">
    <input name="test" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

using the string **iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn**.
Obviously I enable the utf-8 headers on the server first and set the Php default_charset to utf-8 as well as I enabled the mb* override.
As soon as I disable the Suhosin patch and re-submit the form, everything works as it should.

**UPDATE**

I did more tests just to be sure:

```
$test = $_POST['test'];

var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($test, "UTF-8", true));

// Returns true if $string is valid UTF-8 and false otherwise.
function is_utf8($string) {

    // From http://w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8.html
    return preg_match('%^(?:
      [\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E]            # ASCII
    | [\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]             # non-overlong 2-byte
    |  \xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding overlongs
    | [\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}  # straight 3-byte
    |  \xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]        # excluding surrogates
    |  \xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # planes 1-3
    | [\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}          # planes 4-15
    |  \xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}     # plane 16
    )*$%xs', $string);

} // function is_utf8
var_dump(is_utf8($test));
```

and both of the test returned false with the Suhosin patch enabled and true otherwise. The question is: is it a bug or is the expected behaviour? is there a configuration parameter for the Suhosin patch that does something magic about the multibyte strings?

The only option I see at this point is disable the patch unless a brilliant mind give the right advice.

**UPDATE 2**

the GET strings don't get corrupted and are displayed in the browser correctly. Only POST do at the moment.

Comment: You should get some form of an error. Also check your error log. I would also strongly recommend against using the mb_ function override. They will screw up a *lot* of existing code. Better to always explicitly use the mb_ functions when you need them.

Comment: I can't see any error: the string is just incorrectly decoded

Comment: How is it decoded incorrectly? You didn't even mention this in your question. Add details of the actual problem rather than 'it doesnt work"

Comment: Hey Evert, thanks a lot for you help and there is no need to be harsh. The example code I specified is very simple: if I disable the suhosin patch I see the string correctly displayed in the browser otherwise I see question marks: i�t�rn�ti�n�liz�ti�n

Comment: @zekus Just thought instead of var_dump() just use print_r();

Comment: Yea so the thing is.. it *may* still be correct. Take a look at the actual bytes being sent in the POST request. Is it UTF-8? Look at the exact bytes that come back.. still UTF-8? (you can tell because all non-ascii characters will take up at least 2 bytes.

So if this is all true, then you're likely not telling the browser the document is actually UTF-8. The best place to do this, is in the Content-Type header + the meta-tag.

Comment: @Evert, tried that... the string is not utf-8 with suhosin on... starting to think about filling a bug report.

Comment: No it's definitely not a Suhosin bug, you're totally doing something wrong; just unsure what. Perhaps you can put this up on a url so I can take a look.

Comment: The string iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn was worth reading this question by itself, thanks for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a Google search, I found http://algorytmy.pl/doc/php/ref.mbstring.php which mentions

> *Beginning with PHP 4.3.3, if enctype for HTML form is set to multipart/form-data and `mbstring.encoding_translation` is set to On in `php.ini` the POST'ed variables and the names of uploaded files will be converted to the internal character encoding as well. However, the conversion isn't applied to the query keys.*

This doesn't really mean much to me, but it does mention POST variables which seems to be the crux of the issue.

I found, if I set this in my Apache virtual host I could reproduce your problem:

```
php_admin_value mbstring.language       "Neutral"
php_admin_value mbstring.encoding_translation   "On"
php_admin_value mbstring.http_input     "UTF-8"
php_admin_value mbstring.http_output    "UTF-8"
php_admin_value mbstring.detect_order   "auto"
php_admin_value mbstring.substitute_character   "none"
php_admin_value mbstring.internal_encoding "UTF-8"
php_admin_value mbstring.func_overload "7"
php_admin_value default_charset "UTF-8"
```

For reference, this was the php test page I used to reproduce the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<pre><?php echo $_POST['test'];?></pre>
<form method="post">
    <input name="test" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
Test string to use: iñtërnâtiônàlizætiøn
</body>
</html>
```

I tried commenting out the following mbstring setting (or turning it off):

```
; Disable HTTP Input conversion (PHP 4.3.0 or higher)
mbstring.encoding_translation = Off
```

This seems to fix the issue, even though it doesn't make much sense to me because the internal character encoding *is* utf-8??

Another oddness I noticed was that if I set these `mbstring` values directly in `php.ini` (instead of the Apache virtual host), I was unable to reproduce the issue with `encoding_translation` so it seems to be a problem only when `php_admin_value` is used?

Comment: This solution, partially solve the issue: there are still cases that I am investigating where the string is still corrupted by mbstring combined with suhosin.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed?

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

-> http://www.razorvine.net/test/utf8form/utf8pageform.html

Comment: Thanks MasterCassim, but that didn't work either... still seeing the incorrectly decoded string.

Answer (score 0):

Did You try in Your meta tags on HTML page following

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" ></meta>
```

Comment: Hi Roshan, the server headers always override the html meta so there is no need to specify it. Anyway I tested with that as well and the problem is still there.